# React Tree component update state failed

Tags: reactjs, setstate

### Problems

I am new to React , when building a tree component as personal side project , I ran into some issues. When I clicked the tree structure, It was supposed to collapse or uncollapse, but not worked as expected. When I redirected to another component and redirected back, it worked, I tried to add breakpoint to debug, the data for the tree component had been mutated as expected,  I failed to figure out why.

### Code

Tree Component

```
const Tree: React.FC<Props> = ({ data }) => {
  const [stateData, setStateData] = useState({ data: data })

  let keyNodeMap: KeyNodeMap = {}

  useEffect(() => {
    bindKeyMap()
  },[])

  const bindKeyMap = () => {
    let data = stateData.data
    keyNodeMap[data.key] = data
    if (data.children && data.children.length) {
      walk(data.children, data)
    }
  }


  const walk = (children: TreeData[], parent: TreeData): void => {
    children.forEach((child: TreeData) => {
      child.parent = parent
      keyNodeMap[child.key] = child
      if (child.children && child.children.length > 0) {
        walk(child.children, child)
      }
    })
  }

  const onCollapse = (key: string) => {
    let data = keyNodeMap[key]
    if (data) {
      let { children } = data
      if (children) {
        data.collapsed = !data.collapsed
        data.children = data.children || []
        setStateData(stateData)
        console.log(stateData);
      } else {
        // todo
      }
    }
  }

  const onCheck = (key: string) => {
    let data = keyNodeMap[key]
    if (data) {
      data.checked = !data.checked
      if (data.checked) {
        checkChildren(data.children, true)
        checkParent(data.parent)
      } else {
        checkChildren(data.children, false)
        checkParent(data.parent)
      }
    }
  }

  const checkParent = (parent: TreeData) => {
    while (parent) {
      parent.checked = parent.children.every((item: TreeData) => item.checked)
      parent = parent.parent
    }
  }

  const checkChildren = (children: TreeData[] = [], checked: boolean) => {
    children.forEach((item: TreeData) => {
      item.checked = checked
      checkChildren(item.children, checked)
    })
  }

  const renderTree = ({ getPrefixCls }: ConfigConsumerProps) => {
    const prefixCls = getPrefixCls('tree')
    return (
      <div className={`${prefixCls}`}>
        <div className='tree-nodes'>
          <TreeNode data={data} onCollapse={onCollapse} onCheck={onCheck} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return <ConfigConsumer>{renderTree}</ConfigConsumer>
}
```

Tree Node

```
const TreeNode: React.FC<NodeProps> = ({
  data,
  onCollapse,
  onCheck
}) => {
  let children = data.children
  return (
    <div className='tree-node'>
      <div className='inner'>
        {children && children.length > 0 ? (
          <span
            onClick={() => {
              onCollapse(data.key)
            }}
          >
            {data.collapsed ? <FaCaretRight /> : <FaCaretDown />}
          </span>
        ) : (
            ''
          )}
        {data.type === 'folder' ? data.collapsed ? <FaFolder /> : <FaFolderOpen /> : <FaFileAlt />}
        <span>{data.name}</span>
      </div>
      {
        <div className='children'>
          {children &&
            children.length > 0 &&
            !data.collapsed &&
            children.map(child => {
              return <TreeNode data={child} key={child.key} onCollapse={onCollapse} onCheck={onCheck} />
            })}
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default TreeNode
```

### Link

http://chenxiaoyao.cn/one-ui/?path=/story/data-display--tree

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You've set the updated value in onCollapse function.

Comment: thanks for your comments! Could you please be more specific?